# How to count number of particular pattern in a string in R?

Tags: r, string, count

I am trying to count the number of `|` in a string. This is my code but it is giving the incorrect answer of 32 instead of 2? Why is this happening and how do I get a function that returns 2? Thanks!

```
> levels
[1] "Completely|Partially|Not at all"
> str_count(levels, '|')
[1] 32
```

Also how do I separate the string by the `|` character? I would like the output to be a character vector of length 3: 'Completely', 'Partially', 'Not at all'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `|` is meaningful in regex as an "or"-like operator. Escape it with backslashes.

```r
stringr::str_count("Completely|Partially|Not at all", "\\|")
# [1] 2
```

To show what `|` is normally used for, let's count the occurrences of `el` and `al`:

```r
stringr::str_count("Completely|Partially|Not at all", "al")
# [1] 2
stringr::str_count("Completely|Partially|Not at all", "el")
# [1] 1
stringr::str_count("Completely|Partially|Not at all", "el|al")
# [1] 3
```

To look for the literal `|` symbol, it needs to be escaped.

To `split` the `str`ing by the `|` symbol, we can use `strsplit` (base R) or `stringr::str_split`:

```r
strsplit("Completely|Partially|Not at all", "\\|")
# [[1]]
# [1] "Completely" "Partially"  "Not at all"
```

It's returned as a list, because the argument may be a vector. For instance, it might be more clear if we do

```r
vec <- c("Completely|Partially|Not at all", "something|else")
strsplit(vec, "\\|")
# [[1]]
# [1] "Completely" "Partially"  "Not at all"
# [[2]]
# [1] "something" "else"
```

Comment: please can you see an addendum to the question?

Comment: Please see my edit

Answer (score 3):

The pipe `|` character is a regex metacharacter and needs to be escaped:

```r
levels <- "Completely|Partially|Not at all"
str_count(levels, '\\|')
```

Another general trick you can use here is to compare the length of the input against the same with all pipes stripped:

```r
nchar(levels) - nchar(gsub("|", "", levels, fixed=TRUE))
[1] 2
```

Addendum: Use `strsplit`:

```r
unlist(strsplit(levels, "\\|"))

[1] "Completely" "Partially"  "Not at all"
```

Comment: please can you see an addendum to the question?

Comment: See the edit please.